# Protege reasoner highliting individuals of an ontology

Tags: ontology, protege

I have built an ontology on Protege, I ran the Pellet reasoner, and I see that it colored with light yellow color many individuals. This means that my ontology has problem?? How I find what has gone wrong? I don't see any red colored classes as the tutorial here indicates:

https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Using_Reasoners

What should I do?

I got this on log (if it can help):

```
   INFO  13:31:37  REASONER CHANGED
   INFO  13:31:40  ------------------------------- Running Reasoner -------------------------------
   INFO  13:31:40  Pre-computing inferences:
   INFO  13:31:40      - class hierarchy
   INFO  13:31:40      - object property hierarchy
   INFO  13:31:40      - data property hierarchy
   INFO  13:31:40      - class assertions
   INFO  13:31:40      - object property assertions
   INFO  13:31:40      - same individuals
   INFO  13:31:40  Ontologies processed in 28 ms by Pellet
   INFO  13:31:40  
   INFO  13:31:40  REASONER CHANGED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yellow background implies that the item or property has been inferred (non-explicitly described before reasoner was launched). Errors on your ontology will appear in red. I would recommend that you open the `pizza` ontology and check the `IceCream` class as an example on how errors are processed by Protégé.

The log just expresses check settings of the reasoner. For more information please refer to the official documentation as it explicitly addresses part of your concerns.

Comment: Thank you for the useful contribution. It’d be helpful if you provided a link to the relevant location in the official documentation as part of the last paragraph. Could you update that?